# setting a proxy on HttpClient that comes with WCF Web Api?

Tags: httpclient, wcf-web-api

Does anyone know of a way to set a proxy on httpclient that comes with the wcf web api? I just want to be able to monitor all the traffic with fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set a proxy on HttpClient to use fiddler.  If you are hosting on localhost then check these tips here http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic.

if you really want to use a proxy then you can do it like this,

```
var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://..."));
var httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```